# Prevent double MVC Default Controller Invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know, if it is possible for each subsequent request, to not have the default constructor in the controller invoked?

Here's the fake scenario:

I have a controller (HomeController) with 3 Action methods. Now, each method uses a property from a Customer type. I don't want this Customer Type to always be instantiated for each action method.

Sample Code:

```
public class HomeController : SampleController
{        
    public HomeController(System systemInstance)
    {
        base.System = systemInstance;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
       //Do something with the CustomerType
         base.ValidationResult = ValidationEngine.Validate(base.Customer.Address)

        return View();
    }

     public ActionResult Index()
    {            
       //Do something with the CustomerType
         base.ValidationResult = ValidationEngine.Validate(base.Customer.ShoppingCart)

        return View();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve it that upon the first Invocation, I instantiate the base.System Property and then for each subsequent action method, I can just reference the instantiated type.

I dont want to store this type in the Session, or in the Cache.

Hope this makes sense :)

Thank u

Comment: Some questions 1) Is `base.System` static? If not it will be `null` on all subsequent requests? 2) Are you using dependency injection? Can you use some kind of "singleton" logic from your DI container to provide the `System` instance? 3) Should `base.System` be the same for everyone of different per visitor?

Comment: Singleton logic in DI would be the solution, my guess.

Comment: Can we see the `SampleController` class?

Comment: Controllers are instantiated for each request. That's by design as they're not thread-safe (if you used the same controller for multiple requests, users would step over each other with things like HttpContext). You can simply use your DI container of choice to make make your `System` instance a singleton, but you need to be *very* careful with that. It must be 100% thread-safe, and if you're not sure how to achieve that, then you're better off going a different direction.

Comment: Sure Matt

 public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        private System system;
        protected System System
        { 
            get
            {
                if (system == null)
                {
                    system= new System();
                }

                return system;
            }

            set { system= value; }
        }

        public SampleController ()
        {

        }
    }

Comment: Chris, that is very interesting. I didnt know that mate. THanks for the heads up.

Comment: Good article on dependency injection per action in your controller :: http://www.strathweb.com/2014/07/dependency-injection-directly-actions-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Thanks beauXJames. I have done some thinking and will need to overhaul what I have to coincide with the DI approach as well as to make them 100% thread safe as per Chris's comment. I've been doing some reading on Castle Windsor and following their tut's on IoC and it makes so much sense! :)